# Evaluate the iterated integral of this function

Tags: integration

Can someone tell me if my answer is right?

a) Evaluate the iterated integral $$\int_0 ^{\pi/2} \int_0 ^{\cos\theta} r^2 \sin\theta\, dr \,d\theta  $$

[My calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q85b2.png)

My answer is $0$.

Is this correct?

Comment: use proper $tex$ for all your answer please

Comment: Please show your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\cos \theta} r^2 \sin \theta \ dr = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin \theta \int_{0}^{\cos \theta} r^2 \ dr = \frac{1}{3} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin \theta\  r^3\bigr|_0^{\cos \theta}  = \frac{1}{3} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin \theta \cos^3 \theta \ d\theta$$

$$\\$$

Letting $u = \cos \theta$ we have $du = - \sin \theta$ i.e we have:

$$\\$$

$$-\frac{1}{3}\int_{1}^{0} u^3 \ du = \frac{1}{3} \int_{0}^1 u^3 \ du = \frac{1}{12} \cdot u^4 \bigr|_{0}^1 = \frac{1}{12}$$